# How to select certain data in list to convert to dataframe python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list type data

```
file_path = "FQAL.pdf"
df = tabula.read_pdf(file_path, pages='all', encoding='cp1252')
```

And I've got:

```
[   Ticker Live Cusip ISIN  SEDOL             Security Name Security 
Type  \
0    AAPL  037833100  NaN    NaN                 APPLE INC  Common Stock   
1    MSFT  594918104  NaN    NaN            MICROSOFT CORP  Common Stock   
2   GOOGL  02079K305  NaN    NaN         ALPHABET INC CL A  Common Stock   
3    TSLA  88160R101  NaN    NaN                 TESLA INC  Common Stock   
4     UNH  91324P102  NaN    NaN    UNITEDHEALTH GROUP INC  Common Stock   
..    ...        ...  ...    ...                       ...           ...   
63    COP  20825C104  NaN    NaN            CONOCOPHILLIPS  Common Stock   
64  CMCSA  20030N101  NaN    NaN         COMCAST CORP CL A  Common Stock   
65    CSX  126408103  NaN    NaN                  CSX CORP  Common Stock   
66   VRSN  92343E102  NaN    NaN              VERISIGN INC  Common Stock   
67   MANH  562750109  NaN    NaN  MANHATTAN ASSOCIATES INC  Common Stock   

  Currency  Coupon  Effective Date  Maturity  #  Contracts  Par Value  \
0   US Dollar     NaN             NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
1   US Dollar     NaN             NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
   2   US Dollar     NaN             NaN       NaN           NaN
```

I need to select only certain data - Ticker (AAPL, MSFT, GOOGL, etc.) and convert it to dataframe, or one column.
How can it be done?

Comment: That's already a dataframe. To create a dataframe from tickers just do: new_df = df['Ticker']

Comment: I've got after this command: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557